# JS script in header working but not in footer

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

If I place that in my header, just `</head>` it seems to work fine. If I place it before the `</body>` file, it doesn't work.

I checked console and I get this:

```
 [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
    (anonymous function)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    (anonymous function)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    (anonymous function)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    (anonymous function)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    (anonymous function)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
    (anonymous function)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This suggests that you either have inline scripts in your page, or other JavaScript files included, that load earlier in the body and reference jQuery. When jQuery is loaded in the `head` (before them), all is well. That's just a guess, since we can't see the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You have another script on the page that needs to be moved lower than the jQuery script tag.